# How to load MULTIPOLYGON data from CSV into Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, geolocation

I am trying to load MULTIPOLYGON data from csv into BigQuery.

csv data example:

MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.6641550000406 41.95200900002041, -87.66414600001889 41.95172499998634, -87.66413300004291 41.951287000019256, -87.6641250000014 41.950975999991, -87.66411799997235 41.950710999997796, -87.66410699996321 41.95034600003051, -87.6640770000379 41.94925300002996, -87.66406700002733 41.948889000025126, -87.66405600002722 41.948524000007794, -87.66402699996873 41.94754299997942, -87.6640239999718 41.947431999990286, -87.664014999989 41.94706800000302, -87.66425699995835 41.94706299998119, -87.66463300004028 41.947057000019434, -87.66498599997365 41.94705200001454, -87.6652299999552 41.94704900003057, -87.66547100004216 41.94704499999217, -87.66619700000436 41.94703200001018, -87.66643899997062 41.94702899996759, -87.66668100004101 41.94702499997284, -87.66740899996688 41.94701300001905, -87.66765200003078 41.947009999995494, -87.66789300003049 41.94700500002556, -87.66825299997625 41.94700000001595, -87.66861599999213 41.94699100002117, -87.66866599995834 41.946989999984524, -87.66885799997794 41.946990000007425, -87.66886599999077 41.947353999977324, -87.6688750000215 41.947693000027144, -87.66889399995708 41.948214000019604, -87.66889900002306 41.948449000008935, -87.6689069999759 41.948814000013044, -87.66891599997123 41.949179000018155, -87.66894600003023 41.95027399996467, -87.6689559999787 41.950640000027136, -87.66896700002104 41.951005000030705, -87.66897100003573 41.951096999964946, -87.66898999998284 41.951944000026266, -87.6689930000197 41.952100000007114, -87.66900099996057 41.95246599997254, -87.66900800001966 41.95282999997927, -87.66901199997486 41.95299300002933, -87.66903400002491 41.95376499998745, -87.66903799997867 41.953924999970994, -87.66904899998285 41.95428999996699, -87.66874299998453 41.95429399998331, -87.66782499995624 41.9543060000087, -87.66751899999723 41.9543099999868, -87.66718399995784 41.95431399999949, -87.66679100003039 41.954318999986775, -87.66617900001958 41.954326999994244, -87.66584500001142 41.95433199997959, -87.66551799995953 41.95433599999768, -87.66454100003902 41.954349999976834, -87.66421499999196 41.9543549999717, -87.6642069999705 41.95399000002565, -87.6642040000364 41.95383100001683, -87.66418300000497 41.95305699999469, -87.66417899997418 41.95294300000901, -87.6641770000175 41.952896999978314, -87.66416900002824 41.95253299999764, -87.66415999996775 41.95222099998195, -87.6641550000406 41.95200900002041)))

I read the csv data into pandas dataframe, and when i load the data to bigquery using

```
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("geo_column", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.GEOGRAPHY),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df_gps_data, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
job.result()
```

Its inserted the data as POLYGON((*******)) into BigQuery not as MULTIPOLYGON.

So how i can insert the data as MULTIPOLYGON into BigQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are discribing a `MULTIPOLYGON` with only one `POLYGON` inside which is basicaly a normal `POLYGON`.

If you define a `MULTYPOLIGON` as bellow, following this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry), you will have a MultiPolygon in BigQuery.

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)),
((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35),
(30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))
```